# Confusion due to immutable datatypes (PYTHON)

Tags: python, function, types, immutability

I am a beginner and this is confusing me
So, int is immutable datatype. The local variable "num" is copy of x. When we run this code. The value of x does not change. So what is the use of using functions in such situations?

```
students=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
def func(num):
    num+=1
    return num
x = 0
for i in students:
    inp = input("Y?")
    if (inp=="Y"):  
       func(x)
print(x)
```

I get that we need to assign the value to x like this

```
students=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
def func(num):
    num+=1
    return num
x = 0
for i in students:
    inp = input("Y?")
    if (inp=="Y"):  
        x = func(x)
print(x)
```

Is there any way we can assign the value inside the function only?
Also, is there any better way than functions in this particular situation?(Other than just writing x+=1)

Comment: What do you mean with "Is there any way we can assign the value inside the function only?"?

Comment: To "assign inside the function only" you can use globals, that's however almost always a bad idea...

Comment: @Gameplay That's explicitly _not_ assigning "inside the function only".

Comment: I think the OP didn't want to assign the returned value, but change the value inside a function and persist it...It's misusage of word "assign" imho, he wanted to use the `=` operator ONLY inside the function. But that is only my guess, since the description is quite vague. Also do you take inot consideration, that your understanding of the problem isn't always the right one?

Comment: Hi sorry for the confusion

Comment: I meant that can we change the value of x inside the function only
Like instead of x = func(x) I want that it should be a part of the function(func).
so if a students said yes I want that the value of x should be 1 without having to mention that in loop

Answer (score 0):

> So, `int` is immutable datatype.

That's true. `int` values can't change internally (unlike e.g. lists).

> The local variable `num` is copy of `x`.

That's not true. No copies are made. You may be confusing names (`num`, `x`, `func`, ...) and the values held by those names. When you invoke `func` with `func(x)`, the value held by the name `x` is read and the value is passed as the sole argument to `func`, which then assigns it to a local name `num`.

> When we run this code, the value of `x` does not change.

Because `x` isn't reassigned, yes. Only the name `num` gets reassigned to the result of the expression `num + 1`, and that value is returned, but it isn't used for anything.

> So what is the use of using functions in such situations?

In the first example, nothing but wasting a bit of time, since nothing is done with the return value.

> Is there any better way than functions in this particular situation?

In this contrived example that counts how many times the user has replied "Y"? No. I'd write this as

```
num_yes = 0
for i in range(10):
    if input("Y?") == "Y":
        num_yes += 1
print(num_yes)
```

Comment: So in this should we just write 
x+=1
inside the loop?

Comment: Yes. There's no reason to use a function.

Comment: Like this 
students=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
x = 0
for i in students:
    inp = input("Y?")
    if (inp=="Y"):  
        x +=1
print(x)?